# How to display dynamic content in ASP.net using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have two separate `.inc` file which I would like to alternately show based on whether a DIV is shown or hidden (mobile [phones/tablets] or desktop)

Here is my code which is in the `BODY`:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    if ($('#leftNavCustom').css('display') == 'block') {
        alert('mobile');
        <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msMobile.inc" -->
    }
    if ($('#leftNavCustom').css('display') == 'none') {
        alert('desktop');
            <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msDesktop.inc" -->
    }
});
</script>
```

If I remove the two `#include` line, the alert works fine but with the above code, it's neither displaying the `.inc` contents nor is it showing me the alert.

How can I modify the above code to work correctly?

Comment: unless those .inc files actually contain more javascript, this will not work. You cannot just output stuff inside javascript except javascript. To write stuff to the DOM, you might use something like document.write()

Comment: This is server-side include and will occur anytime, so basicly the content of those files is almready displayed in your source, but as you do nothing to display it into your DOM, of course it won't happen. Lol almost the same remark as Reinder Wit :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless those .inc files actually contain more javascript, this will not work. You cannot just output stuff inside javascript except javascript. To write stuff to the DOM, you might use something like

```
document.write('<div class="content">text</div>')
```

Another option would be to output both the .inc files in a separate `<div>`, but hide them using CSS. 
Then in your javascript, you can show the corresponding `<div>`:

**JS**

```
    $(function () {
        if ($('#leftNavCustom').css('display') == 'block') {
            document.getElementById('desktop').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('mobile').style.display = 'block';
        }
        if ($('#leftNavCustom').css('display') == 'none') {
            document.getElementById('desktop').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('mobile').style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mobile"><!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msMobile.inc" --></div>
<div id="desktop"> <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msDesktop.inc" --></div>
```

Comment: I was just about to do that but you beat me to it. Thanks.

Comment: This was easy peezy! :)

Comment: Answer accepted. I don't think the CSS part is needed. Or would you beg to differ?

Answer (score 1):

Or if you're already using `jQuery`, based on [Reinder Wit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414473/reinder-wit)'s solution, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="ms-mobile" class="hide">
    <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msMobile.inc" -->
</div>
<div id="ms-desktop" class="hide">
    <!-- #include virtual ="includeNav/msDesktop.inc" -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var navDisplay = $('#leftNavCustom').css('display'),
            msMobile = $('#ms-mobile'),
            msDesktop = $('#ms-desktop');

        msMobile.toggleClass('hide', navDisplay == 'none');
        msDesktop.toggleClass('hide', navDisplay == 'block');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I will test out both. Thank you for the response. UPVOTED.